# Salt jinja2 and trailing lines inside a loop and if statement

Tags: jinja2, salt-stack, trailing

I can't figure out how to remove the last empty line from the output generated by a `for` and an `if` Jinja2 statments on SaltStack. I couldn't find a post pointing out the solution neither, as the solutions on internet that I could find don't involve for and if nested statements.

Any help is welcome, thanks.

This is what I tried so far:

```
{% for user in list_users -%}
  {% if user.enabled == True -%}
    {{ user.name }}:{{ user.passwd }}
  {%- endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

```
user1:encrypted_pass
user2:encrypted_pass
user3:encrypted_pass
```

I also tried adding `-` at the beginning of the `{endfor}`:

```
{% for user in list_users -%}
  {% if user.enabled == True -%}
    {{ user.name }}:{{ user.passwd }}
  {%- endif %}
{%- endfor %}
```

```
user1:encrypted_passuser2:encrypted_passuser3:encrypted_pass
```

Edit: this is the output that I am trying to achieve:

```
user1:encrypted_pass
user2:encrypted_pass
user3:encrypted_pass
```

PS: I had a look to the [Jinja's whitespace control](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/master/templates/#whitespace-control) without success.

Comment: The output of your first attempt is exactly what your expected output is. What's wrong about it?

Comment: Thanks for answering. The first output has an empty line at the end.